# In mongodb, why is it faster to query indexed subdocument array than indexed first level documents?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, bigdata, database

So this is how my database looks like:

```
> show dbs
admin   0.203125GB
local   0.078125GB
profiler    63.9228515625GB
> use profiler
switched to db profiler
> show collections
documents
mentions
```

A document in mentions is like this:

```
> db.mentions.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51ec29ef1b63042f6a9c6fd2"),
    "corpusID" : "GIGAWORD",
    "docID" : "WPB_ENG_20100226.0044",
    "url" : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taboo",
    "mention" : "taboos",
    "offset" : 4526
}
```

A document in documents looks like this:

```
> db.documents.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51ec2d981b63042f6ae4ca0b"),
    "sentence_offsets" : [
        ..................
    ],
    "docID" : "WPB_ENG_20101020.0002",
    "text" : ".........",
    "verb_offsets" : [
    .............
    ],
    "mentions" : [
        {
            "url" : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.",
            "mention" : "Washington",
            "ner" : "ORG",
            "offset" : 122
        },
        ...................
    ],
    "corpusID" : "GIGAWORD",
    "chunk_offsets" : [
        .................
    ]
}
```

There are 100 million documents in mentions and 1.3 million in documents. Each mention appearing in `mentions` should also appear once in some `document`'s `mentions` array. The reason I store mention info in documents was to avoid going into mentions to retrieve context. Yet when I query mentions only, I thought it should be faster to have an independent collection, `mentions`.

However, after I experimented index on both `mentions.url`/`mentions.mention` and `documents.mentions.url`/`documents.mentions.mention`, and query the same url/mention in both collections, I found it was twice as fast to get response from documents collection than from mentions collection.

I am not sure how the index works internally, but I assume both indexes have same size since there are equal number of mentions in both collections. Thus they should have same response time?

I was trying something like

```
> db.mentions.find({url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C."}).explain()
```

so there shouldn't be difference in network overhead.

Here is the output of

```
> db.mentions.find({mention: "Illinois"}).explain()

{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor mention_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 4342,
"nscannedObjects" : 4342,
"nscanned" : 4342,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4342,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 4342,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 14,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 18627,
"indexBounds" : {
    "mention" : [
        [
            "Illinois",
            "Illinois"
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "----:----"
}
```

and that of

```
> db.documents.find({"mentions.mention": "Illinois"}).explain()

{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor mentions.mention_1",
"isMultiKey" : true,
"n" : 3102,
"nscannedObjects" : 3102,
"nscanned" : 3102,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3102,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 3102,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 8,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 7862,
"indexBounds" : {
    "mentions.mention" : [
        [
            "Illinois",
            "Illinois"
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "----:----"
}
```

And the stats (yeah, I restored the collection and haven't indexed documents.url yet):

```
> db.documents.stats()
{
    "ns" : "profiler.documents",
    "count" : 1302957,
    "size" : 23063622656,
    "avgObjSize" : 17700.985263519826,
    "storageSize" : 25188048768,
    "numExtents" : 31,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 3432652720,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 42286272,
        "mentions.mention_1" : 3390366448
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.mentions.stats()
{
    "ns" : "profiler.mentions",
    "count" : 97458884,
    "size" : 15299979084,
    "avgObjSize" : 156.98906509128506,
    "storageSize" : 17891127216,
    "numExtents" : 29,
    "nindexes" : 3,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 15578411408,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 3162125232,
        "mention_1" : 4742881248,
        "url_1" : 7673404928
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I would appreciate if someone can tell me why this is happening. :]

Comment: Can you share the output for the following: 1) output of explain for your two queries 2) db.collection.stats() for your two collections?

Comment: Dylan, sorry for the late reply. I've updated the question with output of explain() and stats() on collections. Also, I added some further investigation under Asya's answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: The execution plan shows me two reasons why one is faster than the other. Noted that they may not be the only reason. First of all, your subdocument index has 33% greater selectivity. You're scaning and retrieving 33% more documents on the other. The performance is degraded further as a result of the longer running query. Notice that your first query yields 14 times vs. 8 on the other. This means your first query yielding to more write ops, or it might even be an indicator that the working set of your index isn't in memory and it's faulting leading to more yielding.

Answer (score 0):

> There are 100 million documents in mentions and 1.3 million in
>   documents.

There are an equal number of index entries in both indexes because you told us you store mention both in documents and in mentions.

So index access time *is* the same.  The way you can measure that is by running a covered index query from both - meaning you only want to get back the values that are stored in the index:  `db.x.find({url:"xxx"}, {_id:0, "url":1})` says find matching document and only return the value of url from it.  If those two are not equal across the two connections, maybe something is unusual about your set-up, or one of the indexes can't fit in RAM or another measuring related issue.

If those two are the same but fetching the *documents* is consistently faster on documents collection, I would check and see why - complete explain output can show where the time is being spent - and whether more of one collection than the other happens to live in RAM, for example.

Comment: Thanks Asya. There should be same number of _mentions_ in mentions collection and documents collection. However, according to the output of `collection.stats()` I just appended to the question, the index size of `mention_1` is more than 1/3 larger than that of `mentions.mention_1`. And when I do `watch -n 1 free -m`, it seems querying mentions coll consumes twice the RAM space as querying documents coll.

Comment: Although a document in documents coll is definitely bigger than one in mentions coll, the number of matching documents in doc coll is much smaller than that in mentions coll. So, maybe mongo loads results into RAM upon query, and total size of results from doc coll happens to be half of that from mentions coll?

Comment: Turned out `db.documents.find({"mentions.mention":"China"}, {_id:1}).explain()` gives `mills: 98502` and `db.mentions.find({"mention":"China"}, {_id:1}).explain()` gives `mills: 134932`. Confused.